# Twig render string variable as array

Tags: php, json, twig, render

We are using twig render engine, to populate json with payload data.

Or said in other words:

```json
{
    "payload": {
        "sld": "{{sld}}",
        "tld": "{{tlds}}"
    }
}
```

I am looping all variables and "rendering" the values. When everything is strings, it is working perfectly

```json
{
    "payload": {
        "sld": "test",
        "tld": "com"
    }
}
```

BUT, if any of the twig variables is array it is crashing.
Or said with other words:

{{tlds}} is array === ["com", "net"]

because it is stored in json, I can not write it without the string quotes "".

The expected result should be:

```json
{
    "payload": {
        "sld": "test",
        "tld": ["com", "net"]
    }
}
```

Can you help me with a solution or workaround?

Comment: Why are you using twig to render JSON?

Comment: [https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/json_encode.html](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/json_encode.html) might help

Comment: Don't build a JSON string manually. Build an object and JSON encode it.

Comment: The "end customer", via UI is setting what data is required for specific functionality. (Stored in DB in json). We are using twig due to the huge library of tools for manipulating the data. But in the case, when we want to pass the whole array node, we are hitting a huge issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing and brainstorming, I've decided to remove the twig renderer and migrate it to a more simple version.

Long story short, this will render all {{variable.something}} like syntax and will populate it with the corresponding value from the payload.

IF the value is an array, it will json encode it, and after that decode it, in order to achieve the requested functionality.

```php
 private function renderVariables(array $variables = [], array $payload = [])
    {
        $rendered = [];

        foreach ($variables as $key => $value) {
            if (is_array($value)) {
                $rendered[$key] = $this->renderVariables($value, $payload);
            } else {
                $rendered[$key] = $this->replaceMarkdown($value, $payload);

                if (strpos($rendered[$key], '[') !== false || strpos($rendered[$key], '{') !== false) {
                    $rendered[$key] = json_decode($rendered[$key]);
                }
            }
        }
        return $rendered;
    }

    public function replaceMarkdown(string $param, array $argv)
    {
        return preg_replace_callback('/\{\%\s*(.*)\s*\%\}|\{\{(?!%)\s*((?:[^\s])*)\s*(?<!%)\}\}/i',
            function ($field) use ($argv) {
                $field = $field[2];

                if (strpos($field, '.') !== false) {
                    $fields = explode('.', $field);
                } else {
                    $fields = array($field);
                }

                $currentData = $argv; # we should take care for magic before foreach

                foreach ($fields as $currentField) {
                    if (isset($currentData[$currentField])) {
                        $currentData = $currentData[$currentField];
                    } else {
                        return $field . '-not-found';
                    }

                }
                if (is_array($currentData)) {
                    $currentData = json_encode($currentData);
                }
                return (string)$currentData;
            }, $param);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

[As pointed in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64858073/twig-render-string-variable-as-array#comment114669549_64858073), you should use the built in [`json_encode`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/json_encode.html) filter for that.
This said, doing this only would result in an HTML encoded version of you JSON object. In order to overcome this, you will also have to use the [`raw`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/raw.html) filter.

So with this one liner of Twig:

```
{{ data | json_encode() | raw }}
```

And data like:

```php
$data = [
  [
    "payload" => [
      "sld" => "test",
      "tld" => "com"
    ]
  ],
  [
    "payload" => [
      "sld" => "test",
      "tld" => [
        "com",
        "net"
      ]
    ]
  ]
];
```

This will gives you the this JSON (beautified for a matter of readability):

```json
[
   {
      "payload":{
         "sld":"test",
         "tld":"com"
      }
   },
   {
      "payload":{
         "sld":"test",
         "tld":[
            "com",
            "net"
         ]
      }
   }
]
```

<sup>*All of this being testable here: https://twigfiddle.com/i604iv*</sup>